# Plotting multi-line charts in python and embedding in HTML

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am doing some data analysis in python. I have a time series data (for continuous dates) and I want to plot something like :

[image]

I have plotted single line chart using matplotlib and embedded it to HTML using base64 encoding. But the concern is that I do not have hover facility when I embed graphs in HTML.
For the kind of graph shown in the image, I can plot it easily using matplotlib but then I want to embed it in html with hovering enabled for ease of readability. 
I have gone through plotly and that does complete the work but graphs are not private there and privacy is also a concern here.

Please suggest some OPEN SOURCE library for doing this.

Code for what I have done:

```
def graph(data):
    keys = sorted(data.keys())
    values = [data[key] for key in keys]

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (2 , 0.3) ,facecolor='w')
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.15)
    plt.plot(values , color = 'g' )

    imgdata = cStringIO.StringIO()
    fig.savefig(imgdata, format='png' , facecolor = fig.get_facecolor())

    s = '<img alt = "embedded" src = "data:image/png;base64,%s"/>' %
             imgdata.getvalue().encode("base64").strip()


    plt.close()

    return s
```

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for recomendations are off-topic. Although googling for "matplotlib html" does give you a pretty decent option..

Comment: you can check this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955, you may need to expose your data with an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some Javscript to have animated graphs in HTML. You may consider using Bokeh, a Python wrapper to the D3.js library:

http://docs.bokeh.org

Comment: FYI: Bokeh is not now, and has *never been* a wrapper around d3.